# How secure is this method of password hashing and matching?

Tags: php, security, hash, cryptography, passwords

I took information from a series of posts and some prior knowledge to implement the following hashing algorithm.  However there is a lot of talk about what implementations are secure and not secure.  How does my method measure up?  Is it secure?

```
public static function sha512($token,$cost = 50000,$salt = null) {
        $salt = ($salt == null) ? (generateToken(32)) : ($salt);
        $salt = '$6$rounds=' . $cost . '$' . $salt . ' $';
        return crypt($token, $salt);
}

public static function sha512Equals($token,$hash) {
    return (crypt($token,$hash) == $hash);
}


public static function generateToken($length,$characterPool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {
    $token = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($characterPool);

    for ($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++){
        $token .= $characterPool[cryptorand(0,$max)];
    }

    return $token;
}

public static function cryptorand($min, $max) {
    $range = $max - $min;

    if ($range < 0) 
        return $min;

    $log = log($range, 2);
    $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
    $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
    $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1

    do {
        $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
        $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
    } while ($rnd >= $range);

    return $min + $rnd;
}
```

So is this method secure?  Are there more secure methods in PHP for hashing tokens and matching with tokens later on?  Any criticism is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Better post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: is this for swiss bank, lol. This is fine enough.

Comment: @MubinKhalid Maybe...No but a lot of information is stored in users accounts, and there are so many easy ways to hash passwords now that I figured I might as well spend an hour or two to ensure that I am doing it the best way possible.

Comment: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813037/what-way-is-the-best-way-to-hash-a-password

Comment: @MubinKhalid Sweet thanks, let the research begin :D

Comment: My pleasure mate, happy helping :)

Comment: In PHP you should simply use the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions, because they implement all the best practices. BTW where does the `cryptorand()` function comes from, is it ok to pass 0..count as argument or should it be 0..count-1?

Comment: @martinstoeckli The advice to use the build in functionality is OK, but the `cryptorand()` seems to have been included in the source of the question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Indeed, i should really read a bit more careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because you end up trusting `crypt` and you are not using a time constant compare in `sha512Equals`.

There may be platform specific issues too: `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` doesn't have to be cryptographically secure. I'm not sure how you know that `crypt` uses SHA-512 either.

Your calculations in `cryptorand` are slightly off (e.g. for values of `$log` that are precisely on a byte boundary) but that's fortunately kept in check by the do/while loop.

---

Please use the `password_hash` or `password_verify` functionality instead.

Comment: "I'm not sure that those are completely secure given the state of security in PHP, but at least you can blame somebody else" They're as secure as `crypt(3)` is, actually. Ask @ircmaxell for details if you're curious :)

Comment: Hi @HurricaneDevelopment, is this enough to answer the question?

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment I would accept Maarten's answer. It's on-point and contains no factual inaccuracies. (I was merely responding to his parenthetical statement about being unsure if they are completely secure.)